# How to check if local copy is latest with origin

Tags: git

I have a working local copy and how do i check if this is latest with origin ? 
I do not want to sync with latest but need only to check.

What is the command to check the same ? 
How can i do the same using GUI ?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear: do you want to check whether a local branch is in the same state as a branch on origin (i.e. `master` has no differences with `origin/master`) or do you want to check whether the state of `origin` is different from the state that you fetched last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From console you can use `git remote show origin`. You have a section named "Remote branches" and there is the information if the branch has moved or not on the remote repository.

Edit: And if you will script something, tehn you use `git ls-remote origin`

Comment: this link was also more useful, http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/13/list-remote-branches.html

Answer (score 0):

Using cmd try command `git fetch --dry-run`

**[EDIT]**

If you want to pull changes from remote repo use `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

`gitk` might answer your questions. Try:

```
#Retrieve data about origin
git fetch origin

#Open a GUI to check whether you're in sync
gitk --all
```

In this gitk GUI you'll see where are the branches on the remote, where are your branches; and the yellow dot will show where your HEAD is.

This way, you can also easily check the difference between the origin/master, and any other commit